# JQuery Post Request Body Not Received with CORS

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-500

I'm sending a post request with JQuery.

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8082/login',
      method: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        return(true);
      },
      error: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        return(false);
      }
    });
```

The server receives the request but without the payload. This works without CORS, so I'm not sure what the issue is. My CORS setup is very basic and should allow everything.

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true}));
```

Network traffic shows the origin is correct and that the payload is being sent.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX request originator is `http://localhost:3000`? Is the port right? Are you using `https://` locally? Also, check `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` has `POST` enabled

Answer (score 0):

I forget to include bodyParser.

Exact solution was to add this to the node backend file that handled the JQuery POST

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).